# Is there a way to avoid HibernateOptimisticLockingFailureException?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa, optimistic-locking

i have a persistent hibernate managed @entity Obj in Hibernate, which has fields id, fieldA, and fieldB, among others.

In some class i have two @Transactional methods, updateA() and updateB().
updateA() obtains an Obj by its id, does some processing, and updates its fieldA.
updateB does same for fieldB.

I also have two clients that continuously make requests.
One client always makes requests that call updateA(), and the other client always calls updateB().
They both pass the same id of an existing Obj.

Is there a way to avoid the HibernateOptimisticLockingFailureException that keeps occurring, or to handle it once successfully, given the fact that each method updates different fields? Some kind of a merge?

Just to complete the picture, the thread that calls updateA() in fact calls other transactional methods similar to updateA(), but none updates fieldB.

At first I just tried to catch the exception and re-try the operation a second time. But sometimes it fails the second time too... This does not seem like a good solution.

Comment: Are you using versioning (`@Version`) on your entity?

Comment: Not using @Version. Will read about it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can safely do it, the easiest way is to exclude `fieldB` from optimistic locking:

```
import org.hibernate.annotations.OptimisticLock;

/* ... */

@OptimisticLock(excluded=true)
private B fieldB;
```

Comment: wouldn't that fail if two clients concurrently update fieldB?

Comment: @ThomasStets Fail in what way?

Comment: OK, I missed that fact that he only has one client updating fieldB. However, if the are more clients one could overwrite the update from the other without Hibernate noticing.

Comment: @ThomasStets Yes indeed. That's why I said "if you can safely do it". I have a similar case updating a user's last access time. There it doesn't matter too much because in case of a concurrent update, the actual difference between the two values is a couple of seconds at worst.

Comment: Hey, thanks. I haven't tried is but it sounds promising

Comment: Just read about it... Wouldn't that just make updateA() not fail (because the update of fieldB does not trigger a version change) but updateB might still fail when fieldA is updated?

Comment: Depends how you execute `updateB`. If you do a full object save, yes. If you update just the one field, no.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an [automatic optimistic locking retry mechanism](https://vladmihalcea.com/optimistic-locking-retry-with-jpa/).

For that you need to add the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.vladmihalcea</groupId>
    <artifactId>db-util</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Then just mark your service methods with the following annotation:

```
@Retry(times = 5, on = OptimisticLockException.class)
```